# When profiling Go code how to get more granularity in the results?

Tags: go, profiling

I'm currently learning [Go](https://golang.org/) and i've written a [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) parser as a learning exercise. When run it's a little slow and i'm guessing it's the standard library print functions being slow. When i come to profile the program i get a very small report from the pprof tool.

I've basically used all techniques described here to create a cpu.profile:
http://saml.rilspace.org/profiling-and-creating-call-graphs-for-go-programs-with-go-tool-pprof

I build the project and run it:

```
$ go build bfg
$ ./bfg mandelbrot.bf
```

This outputs the `cpu.profile`. I then run `pprof` against that profile:

```
$ go tool pprof --text bfg cpu.profile > report.txt
```

Here are the contents of report.txt:

```
42.56s of 42.56s total (  100%)
  flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
42.56s   100%   100%     42.56s   100%  main.main
     0     0%   100%     42.56s   100%  runtime.goexit
```

Small isn't it? This is pretty disappointing as i was expecting to see standard library and runtime calls and there too and in much more depth.

I tried also generating a callgraph:

```
$ go tool pprof --pdf bfg cpu.profile > callgraph.pdf
```

The contents of callgraph.pdf:

[image]

What am i doing wrong? I wanna see standard library and runtime calls too.

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Go 1.4.1

Comment: How many profiling samples does it show collected? Are you running natively, or in a VM?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, it just happens that your program does not take enough time to be sampled completely. Either increase the amount of computations done or play with `runtime.Set{Block,CPU}ProfileRate`

Comment: The program runs for 40+ seconds. Surely this is enough time to sample correctly?

Comment: The amount of time doesn't matter if it didn't collect any useful samples.  Start pprof interactively and see how many total samples are in the profile.

Comment: @Volker `runtime.SetCPUProfileRate(10000)` had no effect. Any more ideas?

Comment: No idea, I would follow JimB's advice.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the nodefraction edgefraction and node for pprof.

pprof filters the output in order not to overwhelm you.

So in order to make sure I'm not missing anything in my pprof graphs I pass the following flags in addition to my usual flags.

```
-nodefraction 0 -edgefraction 0 -nodecount 100000
```

E.G.

```
go tool pprof -nodefraction 0 -edgefraction 0 -nodecount 100000 -http :8081 cpu.out
```